# Matplotlib Animation FuncAnimation - Header and subhead will be moved

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, title, suptitle

I want to animate a picture in Python with a longer header and subheader. Unfortunately, the graph is moving upwards such that the extra spacing is lost.

```
#%% Import packages

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

#%% Get data

x = pd.date_range('2015-12-31','2020-10-31',freq='B')
y0 = np.exp(np.random.normal(loc=0.05/260, scale=0.15/16, size=len(x)).cumsum())
y1 = 100+(np.random.binomial(2,0.5,size=len(x))-1).cumsum()
df_plot0 = pd.DataFrame(index=x, data=y0)
df_plot1 = pd.DataFrame(index=x, data=y1)

#%% Init und Animate
   
def init():
    return line0, line1

def animate(iTime):
    line0.set_xdata(df_plot0.index[:iTime])
    line0.set_ydata(df_plot0.iloc[:iTime])
    line1.set_xdata(df_plot1.index[:iTime])
    line1.set_ydata(df_plot1.iloc[:iTime])
    return line0, line1

#%% Draw once
    
sns.set_context('notebook')
plt.rcParams['figure.constrained_layout.use'] = True
fig = plt.figure(num='figPort', figsize=(8,4.5),dpi=240, constrained_layout=True)
g_spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=1, nrows=2, figure=fig, height_ratios=[2,2], width_ratios=[1])
sns.set_style('ticks', rc={'axes.grid': True, 'axes.spines.right': False, 'axes.spines.top': False, 'grid.color': 'lightgrey', 'grid.linestyle': 'dotted'})

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(g_spec[0,0])
line0 = ax0.plot(df_plot0, axes=ax0)[0]

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(g_spec[1,0])
line1 = ax1.plot(df_plot1, axes=ax1)[0]

sns.despine(ax=ax0, offset={'left':10, 'bottom':10})
sns.despine(ax=ax1, left=False, bottom=True, top=False,offset={'left':10, 'top':10})
title_main = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor'
title_sub = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna\naliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea\ntakimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy.\n'
ax0.annotate(title_main, xy=(0.025, 0.99), xycoords=('figure fraction'), size=12, ha='left', va='top')  #<-- if 1.01 instead of 0.99, then the height of axes goes to zero
ax0.annotate(title_sub, xy=(0.025, 0.955), xycoords='figure fraction', size=10, ha='left', va='top')

init()
iTime = np.int(df_plot1.shape[0]*3/4)
animate(iTime)

plt.show()

#%%  Animation
anim = FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=animate, frames=range(100), interval=4, repeat=False, blit=True)
anim.save('test.mp4', fps=60)
```

Any help how to place the title and suptitle correctly?

If I use .title or .suptitle, I cannot place the header correctly.

If I use .annotate(), then the axes will take over the complete figure such that I won't see the titles correctly anymore.

If I place the text above 1, e.g. 1.01 instead of below 1, e.g. 0.99, then the axes will be shrinked to zero height - see commentary in code.

I do get the following error messages: "UserWarning: This figure was using constrained_layout==True, but that is incompatible with subplots_adjust and or tight_layout: setting constrained_layout==False."

Comment: It seems that `constrained_layout` with the very long title is screwing everything up. Do you really need `constrained_layout`? You can reserve space for your long title using e.g. `fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.7)`

Comment: ''' fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.7) ''' does not work with x_labels of both subplots.

Comment: Well, my point is that you can adjust the position of the subplots more or less by hand to get everything to fit before you run your animation. Would that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I have used the ax.get_position() and ax.set_position() after the first plot, before running the animation.

```
for ax in [ax0, ax1]:
    print(ax.get_position())

factor = 0.9
box1 = ax1.get_position()
box0 = ax0.get_position()
ax0.set_position([box0.x0, box0.y0 - (1-factor)*box1.height, box0.width, factor*box0.height])
ax1.set_position([box1.x0, box1.y0 , box1.width, factor * box1.height])

for ax in [ax0, ax1]:
    print(ax.get_position())
```

@ Diziet Asahi
How does this translates into fig.subplots_adjust(top = ?, bottom = ?)
Do I need to address different adjustment for the different axes ax0 and ax1?